# Detect deprecated API usage

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tslint

Could you advice me how to turn on deprecated API detection in TypeScript project? I use Visual Studio Code.
What I already did:

- installed eslint: `yarn add eslint -D`
- installed eslint-plugin-deprecate: `yarn add eslint-plugin-deprecate -D`
- installed typescript-eslint: `yarn add -D typescript @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`
- created a .eslintrc file with the following content:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "deprecate"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ]
}
```

Then I ran `eslint . --ext .ts` command in terminal and there were no expected errors or warnings though my code uses deprecated API:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
//onaudioprocess is deprecated
processor.onaudioprocess = event => {
    console.log(event);
    //...
}
```

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? As of v4.0, TypeScript [complains when using deprecated symbols](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38523) (see [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/YmpYBW)).

Comment: TypeScript 4.0.3. Yes, I see onaudioprocess strikethrough but it's not in the list of problems.